# How to log Custom Views in Event Viewer (Windows Server 2012 )

Tags: logging, windows-server-2012, event-viewer, events

I created a Custom View in Event Viewer (Windows Server 2012) that displays events from by a specified source (Sugar2SvcNow Log in attached screen shot). I'm trying to save all the events in this Custom View once per month in a evtx file. For Windows Logs, automatically saving a log is easy to set up by right-clicking on the log name, and then Properties. Is there a way to do the same for a Custom View?

Edit: attaching another screenshot with properties of the Custom View.

[image: attached screen shot]

[image: properties of Custom View]

Comment: Can you display the Properties for the log?

Comment: @Ramhound, I attached another screenshot with properties of the Custom View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PowerShell as described in the Microsoft blog
[Use Custom Views from Windows Event Viewer in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-custom-views-from-windows-event-viewer-in-powershell/):

- In Event Viewer, select the custom view by clicking it
- Clicking *Filter Custom View* from the Action menu or from the right-hamd pane
- Click the *XML* tab
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard
- Open Notepad and paste the text
- Save as an `.xml` file, say in the file `C:\Temp\ev.xml`
- Run PowerShell as Administrator to read the events using the command:

  ```
  Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "C:\Temp\ev.xml"))
  ```

See also the Microsoft documentation for
[Get-WinEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works to output the log event to the screen. I figured out how to pipe the output to 'Out-File -FilePath' to save it in a file. I'm trying to set up a scheduled task that will run this command periodically and save the output in files. Is there a way to automatically increment the file name that the output gets saved to? Or even better, to append the current date to the file name?

Comment: Lots of PowerShell examples to be found. For example, google for "powershell append date file name" gives [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954203/timestamp-on-file-name-using-powershell) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039299/insert-timestamp-into-filename-when-exporting-into-csv).

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.